# Como saber se o $_FILES está vazio?

Tags: php

Olá, testei algumas soluções do próprio Stackoverflow mas não obtive sucesso, ele "pula" o IF e vai direto para o Else, mesmo o campo contendo alguma informação.

```
$tipo_servico = $_POST['tiposervico'];
$nome = $_POST['nome'];
$descricao = $_POST['descricao'];
$img = $_FILES['imagem'];

include "conexao.php";

if ($_FILES['imagem']['size'] > 0){  
    /*Separar o nome da imagem */
    $titulo_img = $img['name'];

    /*Separando o caminho da imagem temporariamente*/
    $tmp = $img['tmp_name'];

    /*Separar extensão */
    $formato = pathinfo($titulo_img, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

    /*Renomeando a imagem*/
    $novo_nome = uniqid().".".$formato;

    if(($formato == "jpg" || $formato == "png")){

        $sql = "UPDATE servico_tb SET
        tipo_servico = '$tipo_servico'
        nome  = '$nome',
        descricao = '$descricao'            
        nome_foto = '$novo_nome'
        WHERE 
        id = '$id'
        ";      

        $editar_servico = $conexao -> prepare($sql);
        $editar_servico -> execute();
        echo"<script>alert('DASDFSDFGFG!');</script>";
    }else{
        //echo"<script>alert('Apenas arquivos JPG e PNG!');</script>";
        //echo("<script>location.href='admin.php';</script>");
    }
}else{
    echo "Erro";
}
```

Também alguns trechos do código HTML

```
<form style="max-width: 330px; padding: 15px; margin: 0 auto;" action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">

            <label><strong>Foto atual do serviço</strong></label>
            <img src="imgservicos/<?php echo $conexao['nome_foto'];?>" width="250px" height="250px">
            <!-- --><br>
            <!-- --><br>
            <label><strong>*Nova foto do serviço</strong></label>
            <h5><strong>OBS:. Não é necessário atualizar a foto.</strong></h5>
            <input type="file" name="imagem" class="form-control"> 
            *Somente arquivos JPG e PNG. <br>
            <input class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block"  type="submit" name="enviar" value="Editar informações">
        </form>
```

Comment: Qual o retorno da variavel $formato? De um var_dump e coloque o resultado

Comment: @LuizGustavoCostaCeolin Tentei aqui, e mesmo usando as soluções abaixo a var_dump retorna alguma coisa, como se estivesse ignorando o if.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a função isset do PHP, ela verifica se a variável foi definida, retornando true ou false

```
isset($_FILES);
```

Ref: http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.isset.php

Comment: Embora este link possa responder à pergunta, é melhor incluir as partes essenciais da resposta aqui e fornecer o link para referência.  As respostas apenas por link podem ser invalidadas se a página com o link for alterada. - [Da Revisão](/review/low-quality-posts/144372)

Comment: Mas eu não coloquei só o link coloquei como ele pode verificar.

Comment: Você deve explicar como funciona e usar o link só para ref

Answer (score 0):

Uma alternativa é utilizar a função `empty()`:

```
if (empty($_FILES['imagem']['size']) != false){  
    /*Separar o nome da imagem */
    $titulo_img = $img['name'];

    /*Separando o caminho da imagem temporariamente*/
    $tmp = $img['tmp_name'];
```

Retorna `FALSE` se var existir e não estiver vazia e não conter um valor zerado. Caso contrário retornará `TRUE`.

Comment: Arrumei, valeu!